# How does fWorldPerScreenWidthPixel work for drawing in loop

Tags: c++

This code draws a sine wave with function.  In the following panning/zooming code, I am trying to understand how fWorldPerScreenWidthPixel is being used to draw the line segments.

```
WorldToScreen(fWorldLeft - fWorldPerScreenWidthPixel, -function((fWorldLeft - fWorldPerScreenWidthPixel) - 5.0f) + 5.0f, opx, opy);
```

It is setting opx and opy, but why is it subtracted from:   fWorldLeft

It seems strange to want to start left of fWorldLeft in the for loop where it draws the line. fWorldLeft starts at -25.

I have included the necessary code to explain:

```
// Draw Chart
    float fWorldPerScreenWidthPixel = (fWorldRight - fWorldLeft) / ScreenWidth();
    float fWorldPerScreenHeightPixel = (fWorldBottom - fWorldTop) / ScreenHeight();
    int px, py, opx = 0, opy = 0;
    WorldToScreen(fWorldLeft - fWorldPerScreenWidthPixel, -function((fWorldLeft - fWorldPerScreenWidthPixel) - 5.0f) + 5.0f, opx, opy);
    for (float x = fWorldLeft; x < fWorldRight; x += fWorldPerScreenWidthPixel)
    {
        float y = -function(x - 5.0f) + 5.0f;
        WorldToScreen(x, y, px, py);
        DrawLine(opx, opy, px, py, PIXEL_SOLID, FG_GREEN);
        opx = px;
        opy = py;
    }
```

Call to set fWorldLeft:

```
// Clip
    float fWorldLeft, fWorldTop, fWorldRight, fWorldBottom;
    ScreenToWorld(0, 0, fWorldLeft, fWorldTop);
```

Sets fWorldleft:

```
// Convert coordinates from Screen Space --> World Space
void ScreenToWorld(int nScreenX, int nScreenY, float &fWorldX, float &fWorldY)
{
    fWorldX = ((float)nScreenX / fScaleX) + fOffsetX;
    fWorldY = ((float)nScreenY / fScaleY) + fOffsetY;
}
```

and while I'm at it, World to Screen:

```
// Convert coordinates from World Space --> Screen Space
void WorldToScreen(float fWorldX, float fWorldY, int &nScreenX, int &nScreenY)
{
    nScreenX = (int)((fWorldX - fOffsetX) * fScaleX);
    nScreenY = (int)((fWorldY - fOffsetY) * fScaleY);
}
```

Thank you!

Josh

Answer (score 0):

Let's break it down

```
WorldToScreen(
    fWorldLeft - fWorldPerScreenWidthPixel, 
    -function((fWorldLeft - fWorldPerScreenWidthPixel) - 5.0f) + 5.0f, 
    opx, opy);
```

A clearer way to write that would be

```
x = fWorldLeft - fWorldPerScreenWidthPixel;
WorldToScreen(
    x, 
    -function((x) - 5.0f) + 5.0f, 
    opx, opy);
```

This transforms the position `(x, f(x))` from world space to screen space and stores the result in `(opx, opy)`. Let's see how these two variables are used:

```
for(...)
{
   ...
   DrawLine(opx, opy, px, py, PIXEL_SOLID, FG_GREEN);
   ...
}
```

This draws a line from `(opx, opy)` to `(px, py)` (which is the current point on the function. `(opx, opy)` is the old point on the function. And this is exactly what you are doing with the initialization from above. You set `(opx, opy)` to a point that is one pixel outside of the screen to ensure that there are no gaps at the border.

Comment: What is meant by no gaps at the border.  How and why would there be a gap there?  What is the gap?

Comment: That depends on how exactly the line is drawn. If the line starts in the middle of a pixel, there would be a gap of half a pixel width. If anti aliasing is used, this might be visible.

Comment: So, why is a maximum gap always less than one pixel?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Why would the line drawn start in the middle of a pixel.  I'm really not understanding, I thought the gap would be a pixel or less so I was trying to understand.

Comment: As I said, it depends on how the line is drawn. If there is no anti aliasing, there will probably not be a difference. You can just try and see what difference it makes to remove the offset.